Jetpack Gutenberg Slideshow Block Not Working or Rendering on Custom AJAX Infinite Load Posts
I'm encountering an issue with the Jetpack Gutenberg Slideshow Block in WordPress.
When I use a custom AJAX function to implement infinite scrolling and load more posts dynamically, the Slideshow Block isn't rendering properly in the newly loaded posts.
The load more posts works perfectly for loading standard post content, but any post containing a Jetpack Slideshow Block fails to display the slideshow correctly. Instead, it just shows the raw block markup without the slideshow functionality.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to ensure the Jetpack Slideshow Block initializes correctly after an AJAX call on success? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your help!
WordPress:
function load_more_posts() {
    $paged = $_POST['page'];
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'paged' => $paged,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($query->have_posts()) :
        while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
            get_template_part('template-parts/content', get_post_format());
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    die();
}


add_action('wp_ajax_load_more_posts', 'load_more_posts');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more_posts', 'load_more_posts');

jQuery:
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var page = 2;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    action: 'load_more_posts',
                    page: page
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#post-container').append(response);
                    page++;
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

